# Version incompatibility issue with logsatsh and elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Logstash 1.4.1 with Elasticsearch (installed as EC2 cluster) 1.1.1 and Elasticsearch AWS plugin 2.1.1.

To try if the Logstash is properly talking to Elasticsearch, I use -

```
bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { host => <ES_cluster_IP> } }'
```

and I get -

```
log4j, [2014-06-10T18:30:17.622]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery: [logstash-ip-xxxxxxxx-20308-2010] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
Exception in thread ">output" org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$3.onTimeout(org/elasticsearch/action/support/master/TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:180)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(org/elasticsearch/cluster/service/InternalClusterService.java:492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:744)
```

But when I use -

```
bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch_http { host => <ES_cluster_IP> } }'
```

it works fine with the below warning -

```
Using milestone 2 output plugin 'elasticsearch_http'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
```

I don't understand why can't I use `elasticsearch` instead of `elasticsearch_http` even when versions are compatible.

Comment: have you tried setting the protocol explicitly when using "elasticsearch"? I would try it with "http", "transport" and "node" and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: which protocol worked?

Comment: @JohnPetrone I only tried "http" and it worked fine, so didn't move to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take care to set the `protocol` option to one of "http", "transport" and "node". The documentation on this is contradictory - on the one hand it states that it's optional and there is no default, while at the end it says the default differs depending upon code set:

> The ‘node’ protocol will connect to the cluster as a normal
>   Elasticsearch node (but will not store data). This allows you to use
>   things like multicast discovery. If you use the node protocol, you
>   must permit bidirectional communication on the port 9300 (or whichever
>   port you have configured).
>
> The ‘transport’ protocol will connect to the host you specify and will
>   not show up as a ‘node’ in the Elasticsearch cluster. This is useful
>   in situations where you cannot permit connections outbound from the
>   Elasticsearch cluster to this Logstash server.
>
> The ‘http’ protocol will use the Elasticsearch REST/HTTP interface to
>   talk to elasticsearch.
>
> All protocols will use bulk requests when talking to Elasticsearch.
>
> The default protocol setting under java/jruby is “node”. The default
>   protocol on non-java rubies is “http”

The problem here is that the protocol setting has some pretty significant impact on how you connect to Elasticsearch and how it will operate, yet it's not clear what it will do when you don't set protocol. Better to pick one and set it -

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/outputs/elasticsearch#protocol

Answer (score 1):

In the [Logstash elasticsearch plugin page](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/outputs/elasticsearch) has mention:

```
VERSION NOTE: Your Elasticsearch cluster must be running Elasticsearch 1.1.1. If you use 
any other version of Elasticsearch, you should set protocol => http in this plugin.
```

So it is not version incompatibility.

Elasticsearch use 9300 for multicast and communicate with other clients. So, it is probably your logstsah can't talk to your elasticsearch cluster. Please check your server configuration whether the firewall has block port 9300.

Comment: This is not the issue here, coz you can see I said that everything works fine with elasticsearch_http.

Comment: I think you have misunderstanding. When you use elasticsearch_http, that's means logstash send the logs to ES by http POST which ES port is 9200. However, if you use elasticsearch, logstash will need to connect to ES which is using 9300 port!!! The warning message you get because logstash can't find your ES by port 9300.

Answer (score 0):

Aet the protocol in elasticsearch.yml:

```
output {
    elasticsearch { host => localhost protocol => "http" port => "9200" }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```